# How to install emacs 24.5 on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, emacs

I'm trying to get the latest stable release of emacs on linux mint (emacs-24.5). But, for some reason `apt-get` only installs 24.3.1. I would usually be OK with that, but I'm trying to use spacemacs, and a lot of the packages require at least 24.4.

I've tried installing it myself, but `./configure` doesn't work (it says I need a whole bunch of libraries, and those libraries need a whole bunch of libraries...), I tried to install it without the libraries, and it only make a bad looking text based terminal only version.

I even tried using linuxbrew, but I couldn't find out how to get the gui working, since I couldn't just do:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

I noticed that ubuntu comes with emacs 24.5, and I'm willing to install that operating system, since i've only been using linux mint for a day. But is there any way I can get emacs 24.4 or 24.5 on mint? A different package manager, something to install all the libraries that the manual make requires.

Also I have already looked on stack overflow and tried this tutorial but it did not work: 
[Emacs 24.4 Released, How to Install it in Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

When I tried to install it myself, it gave me an error about `X` and `gtk` or some other window library, even after I did what all the tutorials said to do to get X libraries.

Thanks for any help and sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this kind of question. Also, ask me if I need to specify what errors I got etc...

Comment: (StackOverflow is a *programming* forum..)

Comment: This is a good question!  If you work out a solution on your own, be sure to [answer your own question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).  :)

Comment: Isn't this Unix and Linux stack exchange?

Answer (score 5):

Use Ubuntu elisp ppa to install latest Emacs snapshot available. After installing you need to run `emacs-snapshot` instead of `emacs`.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

This will install emacs without any further steps. Good luck.

Comment: That works, but ironically emacs 25 isn't officially suported by spacemacs, but it will probably work better that emacs 24.3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it after running these 2 scripts: https://gist.github.com/favadi/18438172892bc4178b27 and
https://github.com/favadi/build-emacs/blob/master/build-emacs.sh

And then when they failed, I went back to the emacs 24.5 I downloaded as a .tar.gz, extracted it, and did:

```
./congigure
make
make install.
```

Those 2 scripts apparently installed the dependencies that were missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general procedure for building with source on Debian-based distros, like Ubuntu and Mint.

Get your dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24 # or emacs24-lucid or whatever
```

Build:

```
tar xf emacs-whatever.tar.gz
cd emacs
./configure --with-whatever # see below
make
```

Install with `checkinstall`.  This basically runs `make install`, but watches which files are installed and automatically creates a .deb and registers the package with the OS.  Then you can e.g. remove it with `dpkg -r package-name`, or copy the .deb to another similar machine and install it.

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

Configuring:

Emacs has a lot of compile-time configuration options.  You can take the defaults or try tweaking it.  I generally use similar options to what Arch Linux does e.g. [this](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/emacs#n27) or [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=emacs-lucid#n27).

Comment: So could you make the .deb on an ubuntu, and then transfer it over to a linux mint?

Comment: @codersarecool Maybe.  I'd only recommend installing a .deb on the same OS, e.g. Debian Jessie -> Debian Jessie or Ubuntu 16.04 -> Ubuntu 16.04.  Obviously the architectures need to match too.  You also need to install the dependencies (the easiest way is probably to use build-dep).  But it might work, and it's easy to undo if it doesn't.