# apt-get build-dep is unable to find a source package for emacs24

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I am trying to follow http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/building_emacs_on_linux.html to install the latest **released** version of emacs (24.5) from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/ on Linux Mint (which has 24.3 installed)

Doing the second step `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24` i get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for emacs24
```

Answers to this [How to install emacs 24.5 on linux mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292184/how-to-install-emacs-24-5-on-linux-mint) did not help.

I tried `./configure` ignoring that step (one can hope), but it gives errors.
What do I need to do to get `apt-get build-dep emacs24` to work?

Comment: Do you have source code repositories enabled in `software-sources` and updated the repository cache?

Comment: That did the trick. Can you make this an answer?

Comment: Mint actually creates an additional file for `deb-src` entries and configures thing differently from e.g. Ubuntu in that respect (although the end effect is the same). I would not recommend using that solution, as it is likely to interfere with the switching on-and-off using `software-sources`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start `software-sources` (from the commandline or from menu, under Administration)

Select "Enable source code repositories" on "Official repositories"
page (bottom),
click [Update the cache] (top right).

Once the cache is updated run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
```